# download a part of html page

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a html page which has 2 sections -- one search section where I have some filter criteria, and the second section where I display the output in the form of some charts, tables etc. I want to be able to download only the second section as is (in the form of html). Is there some way to achieve this through javascript?

I have tried to use Blob object, using something like:
new Blob([  JSON.stringify(data) ], { type: contentType + ';charset=UTF-8' });

But this doesn't help to download charts/images/tables etc. Works only with text content (basically when content type is text/plain or application/json). The data above refers to the actual content I want to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the html `download` attribute.

This attribute can be used on an `a` or `area` element and when the attribute is set it will download file when clicking on the link instead of navigating to the file.

```
<a href="/second-section.html" download>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just saw that the download attribute doesnt work on Safari and IE?    "Note: The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier)." (from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download)

Comment: According to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp it works on IE 13 and safari 10.1 or newer versions. You might detect this with JavaScript and show a message to the user that in order to download that you need to update your browser.

Comment: Or sowing a generic message to everyone that if the download doesn't work you might have to update your browser showing browser compatibility on a tooltip might also be a good idea. But I would still use the download attribute if possible.

Comment: What I did in the past was to load the content on a hidden iframe and send specific headers in the server response so that the file would be downloaded. In case it helps.